# Deserializing Json with numbered keys in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, servicestack

I have such Json:

```
{
  data:{
    "50":{"id":"50","name":"test", etc...},
    "51":{"id":"51","name":"test", etc...},
    "53":{"id":"53","name":"test", etc...},
    ...
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to deserialize this Json?

**[UPDATED]**

I think I must to adjust my question. Is it possible to parse Json using class with description of objects. E.g. I have such class and Json which I parse with *.FromJson()*:

```
public class Data
{
    public ...
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id{get;set;}

    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

What should be instead three dots?

Comment: What do you mean "correct"?  What's wrong with JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your json contains an object `O`.  This object has a member `data` that is a dictionary from strings or ints to your category objects.  So try something like:

```
class Root
{
    public Dictionary<int, Category> data;
}

var o = JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using servicestack.text just do

var v = myJson.FromJson();

Don't forget that servicestack is best used when serialization also made with servicestack.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to deserialize Json object to c# class in JSON.NET project (found on codeplex)

the deserialize example is:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Category>(jsonString);
```